# undefined method `email' for #<User id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Can't figure out what's wrong here. Followed Devise setup instructions, Googled everything I can think of, still no luck.

```
undefined method `email' for #<User id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
Extracted source (around line #7):

4:   <%= devise_error_messages! %>
5: 
6:   <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
7:   <%= f.email_field :email %></div>
8: 
9:   <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
10:   <%= f.password_field :password %></div>
```

Here's my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => false

end
```

I've run rake db:migrate, reset the server, what have you. Still can't figure out where I'm going wrong. I've even got another basic app with the same setup, combing through the source it seems like I've done everything correctly, just can't see the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically your error means you don't have an `email` column (or attr_accessor) in your User model.

I guess you used Devise < 2.0 and now you use the latest version.

Since 2.0, Devise doesn't include the columns automatically to your model anymore, [see this page for more info](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style).

Comment: Ah hah, yes, I was unaware of the change in the update. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Done. So, I have to manually modify schema.rb to include the user column? It seems like that's something it should do on its own...

Comment: don't edit schema! create a migration file (since it appears the migration wan't automatically added to your app)

Comment: Ok, didn't modify schema. :) Added a new migration file manually and edited it to reflect the format on the link you gave me. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you have not `username` column in `users` table.So first create this.

> rails g migration add_username_to_users username:string:uniq

then run `rake db:migrate`. Now you have a username column but it has not be permitted as strong parameters so include following line in Application controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
 added_attrs = [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me]
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

mention *email* column as the attr_accessor in your *User* Model